# Как прочитать конкретные строки не используя номера индекса строк?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Устроил себе задачку тут.
Необходимо прочитать файл приходящий с рабочего ПК на сервер.

Пример содержимого файла:

```
========================================
05-04-21 23:57:08
                               
   Z - ОТЧЕТ ПО Б/Н РАСЧЕТАМ   
                               
по кассе # 1                   
смена # 5883 (ККТ:#312)        
                               
====  Отдел  ГСМ               
   2. АИ-92   *  53,90 р.      
клиент1 15             
          87.29    4704,93 р.  
клиент2 17                       
          45.03    2427,12 р.  
Итого    132.32 лит.           
        7132,05 р.             
                               
   4. АИ-95   *  56,50 р.      
клиент3 16                  
          50.00    2825,00 р.  
Итого     50.00 лит.           
                               
  10. ДТЗ     *  56,70 р.      
клиент4 15             
         111.00    6293,70 р.  
клиент5 17                       
          90.58    5135,88 р.  
Итого    201.58 лит.           
       11429,58 р.             
                               
--------- ИТОГО : --------     
                               
И.П. Монжаренко 15             
         198.29   10998,63 р.  
Торгмонтаж 16                  
          50.00    2825,00 р.  
Энтер 17                       
         135.61    7563,00 р.  
Итого             21386,63 р.  
                               
========================================
05-04-21 23:57:12
                               
       Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ      
                               
по кассе # 1                   
смена # 5883 (ККТ:#312)        
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.  
                       350,00 р
  ост:    24.00                
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.  
                               
Итого:              350,00 р.  
                               
========================================
05-04-21 23:57:16
     Z - ОТЧЕТ ФИСКАЛЬНЫЙ
          Смена # 312
 НАЛИЧНЫЕ  приход  =      35779.83
   возврат прихода =          0.00
 БЕЗНАЛИЧ. приход  =     238187.57
   возврат прихода =       1769.00
 Аванс     приход  =          0.00
   возврат прихода =          0.00

 Сумма в кассе     =   15638107.45

 Н.итог приход     =    9160085.06
```

При этом индексы строк постоянно меняются так что пример в духе:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(25):
        f.readline()
    # в x будет 26 строка
    x = f.readline()
```

совершенно не подходит!

Мне нужно прочитать вот эту часть файла:

```
       Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ      

по кассе # 1                   
смена # 5883 (ККТ:#312)        
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.  
                       350,00 р
  ост:    24.00                
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.  

Итого:              350,00 р.  

========================================
```

Нужно как то обратиться к строке Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ до "========================================" и прочитать все между ними
но необходимого способа я так и не нашел. (в 1С все просто, пропустить/найти/продолжить до), а с python тут не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через перебор строк и простенький алгоритм:

```
with open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

start, end = -1, -1
lines = text.splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ' in line:
        start = i
        continue

    if start != -1 and '========================================' in line:
        end = i
        break

new_text = '\n'.join(lines[start: end + 1])
print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
       Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ

по кассе # 1
смена # 5883 (ККТ:#312)
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.
                       350,00 р
  ост:    24.00
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.

Итого:              350,00 р.

========================================
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через регулярку вытащить

Например:

```
import re

with open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

m = re.search(r'\s+Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ.+?={40}', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(m.group())
```

Результат:

```
       Z - ОТЧЕТ ТОВАРНЫЙ

по кассе # 1
смена # 5883 (ККТ:#312)
  47.Gleid Master -30 жид.
                       350,00 р
  ост:    24.00
 прод:     1.00     350,00 р.

Итого:              350,00 р.

========================================
```

Comment: Спасибо! Оба ответа верные. Но когда присутствует , encoding='utf-8' мне выдает ошибку    
   -----------------------Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProjects\Tovar\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    text = f.read()
  File "C:\Python3.9.2\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 104: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @YanWolf, пожалуйста :) Такое бывает если не угадаешь с кодировкой файла, похоже, у вас там cp1251 :)